# How to load WoW addon after CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED event?

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

Disclaimer I dont know how to code at all and this is my first atempt at rewriting someone elses addon.

I need to check for the following before the addon loads at all.

```
frame:RegisterEvent("CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED");
```

The issue is, I dont know where or how to do that. I tried adding it on line 19 and then changing line 6 to `if event == 'ADDON_LOADED' and arg1 == 'unitscan' and event == 'CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED' then`

The entire code can be found at https://github.com/Damnedprinter/unitscan/blob/master/unitscan.lua

Answer (score 0):

## Bottom line up front:

You have, at a minimum, a mistake in [Boolean logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) where you say
**event == 'this' and event == 'that'**
but obviously something cannot be both at the same time.   You can remedy this using two methods:

- **if  ...  [elseif](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.1.html)   ... end** (*recommended for most situations*)
- **event == 'this' [or](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.5) event == 'that'** (*not recommended*)

## Detailed Answer:

**1. How the original addon works:**

Your code on GitHub is comparable to the following:

```
local frame = CreateFrame("Frame");
frame:SetScript("OnEvent", function(__, event, arg1)
    if (event == "ADDON_LOADED" and arg1 == "unitscan") then
        doStuff();
    end
end);
frame:RegisterEvent("ADDON_LOADED");
```

This creates a frame and tells it to respond whenever any addon finishes loading.  It responds with an [event handler](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Handling_events) that receives the type of the event (as *event*) and an argument (as *arg1*) which can mean different things for different kinds of events.   In this example, *arg1* will be the name of the addon that just finished loading (see [ADDON_LOADED](https://wow.gamepedia.com/ADDON_LOADED) on Wowpedia).

The original author didn't want to do something when just any addon is loaded, so it checks to see that arg1 equals "unitscan" during the ADDON_LOADED event.

RegisterEvent is what causes the handler to be active.  I can see in your source code on Git that there are in fact three different events which share the same handler... so that's why it always checks *if event == 'NAME_OF_EVENT'* to disambiguate which one is happening.

**2. Making it work for you:**

If you want the addon to also respond to [CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED](https://wow.gamepedia.com/CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED) then I recommend using another [elseif](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.1.html) statement like in this example:

```
frame:SetScript("OnEvent", function(__, event, arg1, arg2)
    if (event == "ADDON_LOADED" and arg1 == "unitscan") then
        doStuff();
    elseif (event == "CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED") then
        doOtherStuff();
    end
end);
```

Note I changed the handler to receive two arguments that I arbitrarily called *arg1* and *arg2*.  According to documentation on [Wowpedia](https://wow.gamepedia.com/CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED), these will be the club and stream IDs respectively.   I don't know if you need these ID values for your purposes, but offer it just in case.

**3. An alternative solution:**

*I don't recommend this solution for you!  This is just an alternative.*

If you want to execute the exact same code for both events, then you could simplify the above by using an *or* operator and some parenthesis to control the order of operations.

```
frame:SetScript("OnEvent", function(__, event, arg1, arg2)
    if (
        (event == "ADDON_LOADED" and arg1 == "unitscan")
        or (event == "CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED")
    ) then
        doStuff();
    end
end);
```

**4. Yet another solution, responding to the *comment below* rather than the original question**

If the goal is to [delay execution](https://wow.gamepedia.com/AddOn_loading_process#Order_of_events_fired_during_loading), then you might consider changing from ADDON_LOADED to another event such as PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD.  However, this also fires when you are entering an instance or travelling on the boat to another continent.  As such, the sample code below *deregisters* the event to prevent this frame from acting on it more than once.

```
frame:SetScript("OnEvent", function(__, event, ...)
    if (event == "PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD") then
        frame:UnregisterEvent("PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD");
        doStuff();
    end
end);
frame:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD");
```

Comment: I dont think any of these solutions will work. Im trying to send a message to the chat but the game loads the chat very late (this is when CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED should trigger). So what happens right now and with your suggestions is that addon loads -> condition for addon to trigger is true -> addon tries to send message -> chat loads.  Obviously this means that the message wont be send as the chat is loaded after all the actions has been sent.

Comment: @Damnedprinter  - Added a fourth solution that delays execution.

Comment: unfortunately the fourth suggestion wont work either. PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD happens before CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED so the messages still wont be send to the chat.

Comment: @Damnedprinter Describe the goal, not the step. What does your goal have to do with CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED? http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal

Comment: The goal is to send a message in the ingame chat when the addon is disallowed targeting something (addon tried to do something and the game tells it that it cant do it). This works perfectly every time unless I log into the game, because the ingame chat is loaded very late. The two ways to get arround this I think would be to look for CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED which is supposed to be when the chat has loaded. The other way would be to just add a delay before the entire addon loads but im not sure how to do that either.

Comment: just to follow up on my last comment, one issue with looking for CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED is that it only happens once during the entire play session. If you get a loading screen CLUB_STREAM_SUBSCRIBED does not happen but the addon still reloads.